# Angular display Http GET response body

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

i'm learning Angular and i have small problem with display responded data after HTTP get.

I', requesting:

```
  private url = 'http://localhost:8070/app';
  private descriptors = '/myapp/test';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    getDescriptors(): Observable<Descriptor[]> {

    let params = new HttpParams().set('methodType', 'firstVar').set('provider', 'secondVar');

    return this.http
      .get<Descriptor[]>(this.url + this.descriptors, {params})
      .pipe(tap(console.log));
  }
```

Additionally, i have component

```
  response: any;

  getDescriptors(){
    this.response = this.http.getDescriptors().subscribe();
  }
```

Descriptor[] is only:

```
  export interface Descriptor {
     values: string;
  }
```

And the HTML file:

```
{{ response | json}}
```

and i have response:

```
{ "closed": true, "_parentage": null, "_finalizers": null, "isStopped": true, "destination": null }
```

and error in console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'SafeSubscriber'
|     property '_finalizers' -> object with constructor 'Array'
|     index 0 -> object with constructor 'OperatorSubscriber'
--- property '_parentage' closes the circle
at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
at JsonPipe.transform (common.mjs:4540:21)
at Module.ɵɵpipeBind1 (core.mjs:20893:22)
at AppComponent_Template (app.component.html:3:1)
at executeTemplate (core.mjs:10534:9)
at refreshView (core.mjs:10419:13)
at refreshComponent (core.mjs:11480:13)
at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:10210:9)
at refreshView (core.mjs:10469:13)
at detectChangesInternal (core.mjs:11624:9)
```

In console I see that I've received correct JSON:

```
{values: {…}}
values  :   inputParameters :  (2) [{…}, {…}]
location : "Country"
methodType : "Method"
....
....
and so on...
```

Could you please help me how to get the body answer from request? I see that it is not so obvious like in general JS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the response data, you need to provide a callback function to the subscribe() method. This function will be called with the response data when it's available.

See below an example of how you could the body response.

```
getDescriptors() {
  this.http.getDescriptors().subscribe(
    (data) => {
      this.response = data;
      console.log(this.response); // just to make sure it works
    },
    (error) => {
      console.error(error);
    }
  );
}
```

In this code, the getDescriptors() method now calls subscribe() with two callback functions: one for handling the response data ((data) => { ... }) and one for handling errors ((error) => { ... }). When the response data is received, the data argument contains the parsed JSON object. You can assign it to the response property to display it in the template.

Edit: To filter out the circular reference

```
getDescriptors(){
  this.http.getDescriptors().subscribe(data => {
    this.response = JSON.stringify(data, (key, value) => {
      if (key === '_parentage' || key === '_finalizers') {
        return undefined;
      }
      return value;
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works :) Just one more question - I still have error in console: ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON (added upper). Do you know how to avoid it?

Comment: @Ilkar You should either fix or remove the circular reference from the json. I have added a way to filter them out from your response in the code above. But this is not a real solution if you really required those data.

Answer (score 1):

`.subscribe()` returns a subscription not the content of the stream

```
subscription: Subscription;
response: any;

getDescriptors() {
  this.subscription = this.http.getDescriptors().subscribe((response) => this.response = response);
}
```

Also with this approach you need to unsubscribe when component is destroyed

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe()
}
```

Also you could use `async` pipe that unsubscribe automatically for you like below

component.ts

```
response$: Observable<any>;
getDescriptors() {
  this.response$ = this.http.getDescriptors();
}
```

component.html

```html
{{ response$ | async | json }}
```